# Can I render only part of a scatter_matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scipy

On Python, using the Pandas library, I'm trying to generate the scatter plot of a DataFrame using `scatter_matrix` as follows:

```
scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.5, figsize=(14,14), diagonal='kde')
```

That program takes very long to run and eventually crashes, possibly because there are too many (26) columns, and the resulting image would be to big. Nether less, I noticed I'm able to render 13 variables just fine. That way, one solution would be to generate 4 plots instead, one for each quadrant **of the resulting scatter matrix**, i.e., the ranges `[[0,0],[13,13]], [[13,0],[26,13]], [[0,13],[13,26]], [[13,13],[26,26]]`. Notice those don't refer to ranges on the source DataFrame, but of the target scatter matrix I'm rendering. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried calling scatter_matrix on a subset of your data frame? `scatter_matrix(df[[columns_you_care_about]])`?

Comment: @pault problem is, suppose my df has columns `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`. Using your method, I can plot two quadrants, `['a','b'] x ['a','b']` and `['c','d'] x ['c','d']`. But how can I plot the remaining 2 quadrants, `['a','b'] x ['c','d']` and `['c','d'] x ['a','b']`?

Comment: that does not exactly answers the question if you look for an interactive plot, but an easy alternative is to use seaborn's pairplot function which allows to choose which columns to use for the rows and columns of the matrix with args x_vars and y_vars

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any official way to do it, so I modified the `scatter_matrix` implementation to receive 2 additional params, `cols` and `rows`, which are arrays with the labels you want to compare:

```
"""
This is a modification of the scatter_matrix method;
it allows plotting sub-sections of the scatter plot
matrix. With the official method you can only plot
the entire matrix. This method allows selecting the
`cols` and `rows` you're interested in plotting.
Note that this wouldn't be possible even by calling
scatter_matrix on a subset of the dataframe, because
this wouldn't allow comparing different `cols`/`rows'.
"""

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import pandas.tools.plotting
from pandas.compat import range, lrange, lmap, map, zip, string_types

def scatter_matrix(frame, cols, rows, figsize=None, ax=None, grid=False,
                  diagonal='hist', marker='.', density_kwds=None,
                  hist_kwds=None, range_padding=0.05, **kwds):
    """
    Draw a matrix of scatter plots.
    Parameters
    ----------
    frame : DataFrame
    cols : [str]
      labels of the columns to be rendered
    rows:  [str]
      labels of the rows to be rendered
    alpha : float, optional
        amount of transparency applied
    figsize : (float,float), optional
        a tuple (width, height) in inches
    ax : Matplotlib axis object, optional
    grid : bool, optional
        setting this to True will show the grid
    diagonal : {'hist', 'kde'}
        pick between 'kde' and 'hist' for
        either Kernel Density Estimation or Histogram
        plot in the diagonal
    marker : str, optional
        Matplotlib marker type, default '.'
    hist_kwds : other plotting keyword arguments
        To be passed to hist function
    density_kwds : other plotting keyword arguments
        To be passed to kernel density estimate plot
    range_padding : float, optional
        relative extension of axis range in x and y
        with respect to (x_max - x_min) or (y_max - y_min),
        default 0.05
    kwds : other plotting keyword arguments
        To be passed to scatter function
    Examples
    --------
    >>> df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
    >>> scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2)
    """
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    df = frame._get_numeric_data()
    w = len(cols)
    h = len(rows)
    naxes = w * h
    fig, axes = pandas.tools.plotting._subplots(naxes=naxes, figsize=figsize, ax=ax,
                          squeeze=False)

    # no gaps between subplots
    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)

    #mask = pandas.tools.plotting.notnull(df)

    marker = pandas.tools.plotting._get_marker_compat(marker)

    hist_kwds = hist_kwds or {}
    density_kwds = density_kwds or {}

    # workaround because `c='b'` is hardcoded in matplotlibs scatter method
    #kwds.setdefault('c', plt.rcParams['patch.facecolor'])

    cols_boundaries_list = []
    for a in cols:
        values = df[a]#.values[mask[a].values]
        rmin_, rmax_ = np.min(values), np.max(values)
        rdelta_ext = (rmax_ - rmin_) * range_padding / 2.
        cols_boundaries_list.append((rmin_ - rdelta_ext, rmax_ + rdelta_ext))
    rows_boundaries_list = []
    for a in rows:
        values = df[a]#.values[mask[a].values]
        rmin_, rmax_ = np.min(values), np.max(values)
        rdelta_ext = (rmax_ - rmin_) * range_padding / 2.
        rows_boundaries_list.append((rmin_ - rdelta_ext, rmax_ + rdelta_ext))

    for i, a in zip(lrange(w), cols):
        for j, b in zip(lrange(h), rows):
            ax = axes[i, j]

            if cols[i] == rows[j]:
                values = df[a]#.values[mask[a].values]

                # Deal with the diagonal by drawing a histogram there.
                if diagonal == 'hist':
                    ax.hist(values, **hist_kwds)

                elif diagonal in ('kde', 'density'):
                    from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
                    y = values
                    gkde = gaussian_kde(y)
                    ind = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 1000)
                    ax.plot(ind, gkde.evaluate(ind), **density_kwds)

                ax.set_xlim(cols_boundaries_list[i])

            else:
                #common = (mask[a] & mask[b]).values
                ax.scatter(df[b], df[a], marker=marker, **kwds)

                ax.set_xlim(rows_boundaries_list[j])
                ax.set_ylim(cols_boundaries_list[i])

            ax.set_xlabel(b)
            ax.set_ylabel(a)

            if j != 0:
                ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
            if i != w - 1:
                ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)

    # what is that for?
    #if len(df.columns) > 1:
        #lim1 = cols_boundaries_list[0]
        #locs = axes[0][1].yaxis.get_majorticklocs()
        #locs = locs[(lim1[0] <= locs) & (locs <= lim1[1])]
        #adj = (locs - lim1[0]) / (lim1[1] - lim1[0])

        #lim0 = axes[0][0].get_ylim()
        #adj = adj * (lim0[1] - lim0[0]) + lim0[0]
        #axes[0][0].yaxis.set_ticks(adj)

        #if np.all(locs == locs.astype(int)):
            ## if all ticks are int
            #locs = locs.astype(int)
        #axes[0][0].yaxis.set_ticklabels(locs)

    pandas.tools.plotting._set_ticks_props(axes, xlabelsize=8, xrot=90, ylabelsize=8, yrot=0)

    return axes
```

I was quite careless modifying that code so it is probably broken but served my needs.

Answer (score -1):

The 4 quadrants will be:

```
mid_ind = len(df.index)//2
mid_col = len(df.columns)//2

df.iloc[:mid_ind,:mid_col]
df.iloc[mid_ind:,:mid_col]
df.iloc[mid_ind:,mid_col:]
df.iloc[:mid_ind,mid_col:]
```

Comment: @MaiaVictor yes, iloc is your new friend.

Comment: Actually... rethinking... it doesn't seem to do what I want. Look at [this snippet](http://pastebin.com/raw/kaprSqXR) to see the difference. Please, tell me I'm not going crazy... this is different, right?

Comment: This method slices quadrants. If you want other slices adapt the parameters you use in the slice. If you talk a b * a b then it snot quadrants you are talking about anymore, not it s not what your OP is about

Comment: I guess you're right, I've edited the OP to better express what I'm trying to do. Is it correct now?

Comment: What isn't clear? `scatter_plot` on my dataset generates a 26x26 matrix, I want to split it into four 13x13 chunks... that is just it...